# Getting the sender from Outlook.MailItem returns null

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to get the sender (From) of an Outlook.MailItem without success. It returns null.

I have tried below.

Attempt 1:

```
string from = omi.SenderEmailAddress;
```

Attempt 2:

```
var exch = omi.Sender.GetExchangeUser(); // it returns null
if (exch != null)
{
    string from = exch.PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

Also I have checked omi.SenderEmailType to see what type is, and it returns null.

Note: omi is an Outlook.MailItem object.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the sender related properties are only populated on the received or already sent messages. If you are accessing these properties on a message being submitted, they won't be present until the message is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.

Comment: My Outlook.MailItem (omi) is already in the inbox. I am trying to obtain the "from" once the omi is in the inbox (received), not before.

Comment: Does Outlook show the sender? Is `SentOnBehalfOfName` property populated? What do you see for the sender related properties n MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `SendUsingAccount` property. If it is not set then you can use the [Namespace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object.

Comment: AFAIK SendUsingAccount returns the account from which you are sending the email but I do not want this. I want the sender's email (from).

Comment: You can check the account email address.

Comment: How I can check the account email address? I highly appreciate if you can post a piece of code. thx.

Comment: You may use the following sequence of calls - `Namespace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address` or `Namespace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Outlook.MailItem that is not null, you should be able to follow this process to retrieve the sender's email address, adapted from the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-the-smtp-address-of-the-sender-of-a-mail-item).

```
string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

if (omi == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
if (omi.SenderEmailType == "EX")
{
    Outlook.AddressEntry sender = omi.Sender;
    
    if (sender != null)
    {
        // Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
        if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry ||
            sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
        {
            // Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
            
            if (exchUser != null)
            {
                return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
else
{
    return omi.SenderEmailAddress;
}
```

Comment: The sender-related properties are set when the message was sent. Before submitting items you will not find such properties set for items.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev They wrote in one of their comments the email was already received in the inbox - "My Outlook.MailItem (omi) is already in the inbox. I am trying to obtain the "from" once the omi is in the inbox (received), not before."